# How can I prevent Slack from replacing ":)" with some emoji when I write a message?

Tags: slack, emoji

By default, Slack replaces `:)` with some emoji when I write a message.

How can I prevent Slack from replacing ":)" with some emoji when I write a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set your personal emoji preferences](https://slack.com/help/articles/4406393601683-Manage-emoji-preferences#emoji-display-preferences) in Slack Preferences, in the section called "Messages & Media".

Deactivate the checkbox for *"Convert my typed emoticons to emoji"* there.
[image: Screenshot of the "Preferences" dialogue in Slack, opened at "Messages & media". Option for "Convert my typed emoticons to emoji" shown.]